# A characterization of continuity

Tags: calculus, continuity

A set $O \subset \mathbb R$ is open if for any $x \in O$ there exists $ \eta  > 0$ such that $(x - \eta, x + \eta) \subset O$.

How can it be proved that if $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is continuous and $O$ is open, then 
$$f ^{-1}(O) := \{x \in \mathbb R : f(x) \in O\}$$
 is open?

Comment: What is your definition of continuity?

Comment: @John The function f is continuous at some point c of its domain if the limit of f(x) as x approaches c through the domain of f exists and is equal to f(c)

Comment: Are you familiar with the $\epsilon-\delta$ of continuity? If yes, you've an answer already.

Comment: yeah I am familiar but have some issues in understanding that

Comment: I suggest that you write down your understanding and state what do you not understand in the question (by editing the question), so that people can easier answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Claim**: Let $X$ and $Y$ be metric spaces, and $f : X\rightarrow Y$ is a continuous function then we claim that preimage of open set is an open set.

Suppose $f$ is continuous let $U\subseteq Y$ be open, if $U$ is empty it's preimage is empty and hence open. So we assume that $U, f^{-1}(U)$ are non-empty. Let $x\in f^{-1}(U)$, as $f$ is continuous, for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists a $\delta>0$ such that $d_X(x,x')<\delta$ implies $d_Y(f(x),f(x'))<\epsilon$.

So pick $\epsilon>0$ such that $B(f(x),\epsilon)\subseteq U$, (we can do this as $U$ is open), then there is a $\delta>0$ such that for all $x'$ such that $d_X(x,x')<\delta$, $d_Y(f(x),f(x'))<\epsilon$. But then $f(B(x,\delta))\subseteq B(f(x),\epsilon)\subseteq U$, therefore $B(x,\delta)\subseteq f^{-1}(U)$ and so the preimage is open.
[Now for your problem you can assume $X=Y= \mathbb R$]